# Cannot load pepper flash plugin in QtWebEngine with Qt5.6

Tags: qt, flash, qtwebengine, qt5.6

I made a simple web browser but when I access to

https://get.adobe.com/jp/flashplayer/

It says

```
Adobe Flash Player is already installed, but disabled
```

However as I read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html
It says that pepper flash plugin should be automatically loaded if there is a proper dll file. I checked my C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\ and I'm sure that I have a pepflashplayer32_21_0_0_213.dll there.

Then I also set

```
QWebEngineSettings *websetting = QWebEngineSettings::defaultSettings();
websetting->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

but still no hopes.
Anyone knows how to enable flash with QtWebEngine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I got a working answer here:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/66187/cannot-load-pepper-flash-plugin-in-qtwebengine-with-qt5-6/3

For me I have to copy pepflashplayer.dll from chrome. It seems that installed pepflashplayer*.dll from adobe does not work.

Answer (score 1):

After installing PepFlashPlayer, you need to enable PPAPI in your application manually (it is disabled by default). Use following code before showing the page:

```
QWebEngineSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Comment: Consider this from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#globalSettings) : _Any setting changed on the default object is automatically applied to all QWebEnginePage instances where the particular setting is not overridden already._

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it manually with this command line argument:

```
--ppapi-flash-path=./libpepflashplayer.so
```

See also the different bug reports relative to this problem : [51774](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51774) and 
[49625](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49625).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm targeting windows only. Where can I find libpepflashplayer.so or any similar thing for windows?

Comment: For me, it is here : `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\ ` . If you use a 64bit version, you may change `System32` in `SysWOW64`.

Comment: I have pepflashplayer64_21_0_0_213.dll under this path but did not find any .so file.

Comment: oops, I'm using a different stackoverflow account here at home.